# Mysql display one colum if sender id and receiver id values mathes in any of the colums

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How do i display single record from database if two columns match back and fort

Perhaps an example would be clearer. Given a table called filters, I have 3 columns (id, sender_id, receiver_id):

```
---+-------------------+--------------+
id | sender_id         | receiver_id  |  
---+-------------------+--------------+
1  | 1                 | 2            |  
2  | 2                 | 1            |  
3  | 3                 | 4            | 
4  | 4                 | 3            |  
---+-------------------+--------------+
```

If `sender_id 1` sent message to `sender_id 2` and
`sender_id 2` sent message back to `sender_id 1` then they are one conversation and should only display one record the result i want for table above is :

```
---+-------------------+--------------+
id | sender_id         | receiver_id  |  
---+-------------------+--------------+
1  | 1                 | 2            |  
3  | 3                 | 4            |   
---+-------------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the ordering, you can use aggregation:

```
select min(id), least(sender_id, receiver_id), greatest(sender_id, receiver_id)
from t
group by least(sender_id, receiver_id), greatest(sender_id, receiver_id);
```

Note:  This can return a pair that is not in the original data -- if the pair is not there.

An alternative which is probably faster with the right indexing is:

```
select t.*
from t
where sender_id < receiver_id or
      not exists (select 1 
                  from t t2
                  where t2.receiver_id = t.sender_id and t2.sender_id = t.receiver_id
                 );
```

Comment: Can this be improved to return the most recently  created record only by comparing a new field called timestamp ?

Comment: @AvyeLe . . . That would be a different question from the one you have asked here.